# How to use serverUrl from salesforce login request in subsequent calls

Tags: soap, wsdl, python

I am working on a application where I need to use salesforce data replication api to get deleted/updated record id but this facility is available through **SOAP** api and examples are provided in java/c#. I have to Implement the same in python which I did in bulk api data but for data replication methods like **getUpdated** or **getDeleted** I have to use external library like [zeep](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/) using salesforce provided WSDL xml file.

Using WSDL is fine I am getting all services but to Implement the subsequent services we need to pass **sessionHeader and serverUrl** which we received from login api, I can successfully set the session header using **set_default_soap_header** but unable to set the **serverURL** thing. The soap header function from WSDL throws exception of SessionHeader signature If I passed the serverUrl.

From salesforce [doc](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/218/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/apex_api.pdf), I refer this [java](https://pastebin.com/Hx5gxjTT) example to check the url attribute to set the serverUrl from login response but didn't succeed using soap client in python.

Am I misguided or headed in wrong direction ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer to work with REST APIs in Python, the REST API provides equivalent endpoints:

- [sObject Get Updated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm)
- [sObject Get Deleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getdeleted.htm)

Communicating with these endpoints shouldn't require any additional libraries (other than whatever you're already using, like `simple_salesforce` or `requests`).

Comment: Yes this one is pretty straightforward through rest, though it's not available on simple_salesforce but it provides fruitful information require by updated and deleted api endpoints. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can often use the `restful()` method in simple_salesforce to call other APIs that aren't explicitly supported.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP login method will return a `serverURL` that is appropriate for further usage with the API that you logged into.

More likely than not, you performed the [`login()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) call against the Partner API.

The resulting `serverURL` would have been something like:

```
https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/45/00D300000000001
```

The **na1** would have been changed to your specific pod, or even your custom MyDomain setting.

This serverURL is important, as all subsequent API requests need to go there instead of https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/45.0/ 
I.e. You don't pass the serverURL to Salesforce in the headers. It **is** the endpoint that you communicate via.

I'll admit to knowing next to nothing about how to reconfigure the SOAP endpoint in Python. However, I found [Change Service URL in Python Zeep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42236251/54026), which seems like it should be applicable here. You need to create [a new ServiceProxy object](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/client.html#creating-new-serviceproxy-objects) using the endpoint defined in the serverURL.

Comment: Thanks for help, let me go through with proxy object.